# Glyph origin of 鐵

Tags: glyph-origin

I've never seen  in any other character before, so I'll take that  is exclusively for 鐵 (just like 邊 and 微 which I've asked before in the past). So where does  come from? It seems to be a combination of relatively unrelated components, and none of them sound like 鐵.

Comment:  | 同【国】。Nothing to do with 鐵.

Comment: @Mou某 reading that as 「國」 looks like a 同形異字 (「或」+「王」+ ...). The component in 「鐵」 is 「戈」+「呈」 + ...

Comment: @Mou某 戜 (U+621C) and  (U+229CC) were indeed easily conflated.

Comment: @Michaelyus Not to mention U+229DC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「鐵」 ([Zhengzhang OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995)): **/*l̥ʰiːɡ/**, *black metal* > *iron*) is comprised of semantic 「金」 (*metal*) and phonetic 「」 (**/*l'iɡ/**, using the reconstruction of 「秩」)*. 「」 (top-left component 「大」) was later corrupted into 「」 (top-left component 「十」).

「鐵」 represents the same word as 「驖」 (*black horse*), which also uses the component 「」. If you recursively trace the components downwards, you eventually end up with a phonetic 「呈」 (**/*rleŋ/**).

---

* [《說文・大部》](https://www.shuowen.org/view/6572?bushou=%E5%A4%A7)，大也。从大聲。讀若《詩》「大猷」。[《詩・巧言》](https://ctext.org/book-of-poetry/qiao-yan/zh)：秩秩大猷、聖人莫之。